# Hibernate is not working on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, thinkpad, hibernate

I have a lenove t510 i7 8GB ram and 8.5GB of swap that I allocated when installing. I followed [this article](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-17-10/) steps but when I am running :

```
sudo apt install pm-utils && sudo pm-hibernate
```

the computer is not shutting down but it is going into sleep with only one option left for me of shutting down by force and then restart it

I use my computer for coding hibernating one of the action perform everyday ...I am blocked with ubuntu..coming from windows 7.

In power management(settings) I have set power button click to hibernate the computer ...but when I click nothing happens.

My **/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla**

```
> [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
> Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;
> ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Change CPU Frequency scaling]
> Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=org.gnome.cpufreqselector;org.mate.cpufreqselector
> ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Setting the clock] Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=org.gnome.clockapplet.mechanism.*;org.gnome.controlcenter.datetime.configure;org.kde.kcontrol.kcmclock.save;org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-time;org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-timezone;org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-local-rtc;org.freedesktop.timedate1.set-ntp;com.canonical.controlcenter.datetime.configure;org.mate.settingsdaemon.datetimemechanism.settime
> ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Adding or changing system-wide NetworkManager connections]
> Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system
> ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Update already installed software]
> Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages ResultActive=yes
> 
> [usb-creator] Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=com.ubuntu.usbcreator.mount;com.ubuntu.usbcreator.image
> ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Printer administration]
> Identity=unix-group:lpadmin;unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.* ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Disable hibernate by default in upower] Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Disable hibernate by default in logind] Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
> ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Modify error reporting settings]
> Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=com.ubuntu.whoopsiepreferences.change ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Allow admins to set the hostname,locale,keyboard,date/time without
> prompting] Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
> Action=org.freedesktop.locale1.set-locale;org.freedesktop.locale1.set-keyboard;org.freedesktop.hostname1.set-static-hostname;org.freedesktop.hostname1.set-hostname
> ResultActive=yes
> 
> [Re-enable hibernate for multiple users by default in logind]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
> ResultActive=yes
```

My **/etc/fstab** :

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=28bad0ab-1636-4d6a-a4b5-acd6cd28d96c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=c6d149ab-c9e7-400a-87c9-23a3900c4e07 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=5e879d19-6324-477d-9bd8-a7a096075b04 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

My **/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume** :

```
RESUME=UUID=1abeab9d-c8d9-40bd-af1d-26dbc6421b20
```

The command  **sudo swapon -s** output :

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-0                               partition   8299004 0   -1
```

Here is the screenshot of the disk manager(Refusing to activate the swap too) :

[image]

[image]

My BIOS information are :  BIOS 1.41, MT-M 4349A99, RAM 8192MB and the power management configuration in BIOS is :

[image]

Comment: You could try [tuxonice kernel](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and try to hibernate via `systemctl hibernate`.

Comment: I gave up on ubuntu  and went back to win 10....even my wired network was not working ... personnaly here are things I didn't like about it : No file copying or moving progression windows accessible from  the dock
Drag and drop is not known in ubuntu 17.10...I was trying to drag music from
 a folder to drop to vlc but nothing worked
Take long to load (to boot 46seconds and 5sec to open a software) on i7 8GB RAM
Difficult to put a shortcut to a folder on the dock(for instance a simple drag drop)
No way to see directly from filemanager HDD usage